# How to Remove every alternate element from a circular linked list

Tags: python

Remove every alternate element from a circular linked list in python.

example:
input-1-->2-->3-->1(head). 
output-1-->3-->1(head)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you keep track of the head (and stop when you reach the head), all you have to do is iterate through the list and set the current element's next variable to element.next.next. This skips and removes every alternate element until you reach the head again.

Comment: in case of 1-->2-->3-->1(head). it goes from 1-->3 and once it's on 3 again it will go to next of next means 3 .this way it will keep on going and wont break.

Comment: Fair point - you could just have a check to break the loop if the next element also points to the head. That way, if the next element points to the head, then there's no need to for the loop to continue on further, so the algorithm ends.

Comment: I am sorry I am asking a silly question here..but what will happen when I have.         input 1-->2-->3-->4-->1(head)  and i need output as 1-->3-->1(head) . I won't be able to remove 4 then I think and I can't have check in starting as I will be starting from the head node itself.

Comment: In the example you gave, we first do a check if 1.next (which is 2) is the head (which it is not), so the algorithm would make 1.next to point to 1.next.next, which would be 3. So now you have 1-->3-->4-->1(head). Then you go to 1.next (which is now 3). Do a check if 3 or 3.next is the head (which it is not), so continue with the algorithm. Now make 3.next point to 3.next.next which would now be 1(head). Now you have 1-->3-->1(head). Then you go to 3.next (which is now 1(head)). Do a check if 1(head) or 1(head).next is the head. This is true, so we stop the algorithm.